# Is there any theorem that relates the divergence and surface integrals with line integrals?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products

I have the surface integral of the divergence of some vector/tensor field, and I'm wondering if there is any theorem similar to the divergence theorem, for surface integrals?

Comment: It must be Stockes theorem.

Comment: The "related" tab to the right shows that [this has been asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130081/does-the-divergence-theorem-work-on-a-surface?rq=1).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I guess I tried to look first but the question was made in a different way. Thank you, I'm new here...