# Deriving a boundary flux version of Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

Just like how there is a flux version of Green's theorem, I want to derive a version of stokes theorem where you integrate the flux of the field perpendicular to the boundary of S. Intuitively it should be related to some kind of projection of the divergence of F over the surface. Given the usual setup of stokes, with surface S, vector field F, tangent vector to the boundary T, and normal vector n. The vector $\vec{P}$ is the vector perpendicular to $\partial S$ and parallel to S. It is given by
$$\vec{T}\times\vec{n}=\vec{P}\\$$
This vector points outwards according to RHR.
I want to relate the following line integral to some type of divergence of F over S.
$$\oint_{\partial S}^{}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{P}ds\\$$
$$=\oint_{\partial S}\vec{F}\cdot(\vec{T}\times\vec{n})ds\\$$
$$=\oint_{\partial S}(\vec{n}\times\vec{F})\cdot\vec{T}ds\\$$
$$=\oint_{\partial S}(\vec{n}\times\vec{F})\cdot d\vec{r}\\$$
$$=\iint_S (\nabla\times(\vec{n}\times\vec{F}))\cdot\vec{n} d\sigma\\$$
I tried using an identity involving the curl of a cross product, but I wasn't able to get anywhere with that. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You are on the right track... you are trying to derive the divergence theorem, or Gauss' theorem.  It is all part of the generalized Stokes theorem.  The integral of a function over the boundary of and oriented manifold is equivalent of integrating the derivative of that function of the over the interior the manifold.  Over a closed surface, the flux across the surface equals the integral of the divergence over the volume.  $\iint F\cdot dS = \iiint \nabla \cdot F dV.$

Comment: I'm aware of the divergence theorem, but I'm trying to find something else. I want to take the flux version of greens theorem (integrating the divergence over a 2d region), and then apply that to 'curvy' surfaces in space. Stokes does this, but only for the curl form of greens theorem. Divergence theorem integrates divergence over a volume, which is different from a 2d region

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Divergence Theorem Work on a Surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130081/does-the-divergence-theorem-work-on-a-surface)

Comment: @MarkS. It does actually. Never noticed it was on the right sidebar lol. I guess I was close. Thank you

Comment: I might be missing something, but it might be on the right sidebar because my close vote linked it, not because it was always there.